# Boxplot: label an outlier

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot, outliers

I'm working with the airquality dataset and I saw this in another post. I'd like to print the number of the observation for the 3 outliers instead of the value of those points, is there a way to do that? I mean, what I want is to print the index within the Wind vector of those 3 outliers, not their values. Thanks

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
a=boxplot(airquality$Wind,plot=FALSE)
qplot(y=airquality$Wind,geom='boxplot')+
annotate(geom="text",x=rep(0.1,length(a$out)),
y=a$out,label=a$out,size=2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you define an outlier? Are you using the internal logic for boxplot or something else?

Comment: The boxplot criteria. I know I can find the index by doing

out1 <- boxplot.stats(Wind)$out

which(Wind %in% c(out1))

but I'd like to know if these values can be printed nicely in the plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by printing the values nicely; here's a plot with the observation index printed; you can adjust appearance with the annotate arguments.

```r
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

a = boxplot(airquality$Wind, plot = FALSE)

qplot(y = airquality$Wind, geom = 'boxplot') +
  annotate(geom = "text",
           x = rep(0.1, length(a$out)),
           y = a$out,
           label = which(airquality$Wind  %in%  a$out),
           size = 2.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, with "nicely" I meant that if the outliers are very very close together, maybe the numbers of the corresponding observations will be overlapped and illegible